# Finding duplicates in table and then finding max from results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Got a table with DeviceName, IPaddress and CreateTime.

I need to find devices with duplicate IPs but only show the device with the latest create time.  This is in MSSQL

I got the devices with duplicate IPs but I can't figure out how to only display the one that was created last .  Having trouble getting the results using Max(CreateTime)

So far I have this query to find the devices with duplicate IPs

```
select devicename,IPAddress from devices where ipaddress IN  
(SELECT IPAddress   FROM Devices    GROUP BY  IPAddress    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where d.createtime = (select max(d2.createtime)
                      from devices d2
                      where d2.ip = d.ip
                     );
```

If you also want to eliminate duplicates, you can do:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where d.createtime = (select max(d2.createtime)
                      from devices d2
                      where d2.ip = d.ip
                     ) and
      exists (select 1
              from devices d2
              where d2.ip <> d.ip
             );
```

Comment: I do not believe that OP needs devices *without* duplicate IPs in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I might consider `Rank` function like below. it will rank all duplicate IPs by createdate and then selects all IP addresses with first rank only.

```
select 
    devicename, 
    IPAddress 
From
(
  select 
    devicename,
    IPAddress 
    Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY IPAddress ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS Rnk
  from devices
) Query
Where rnk = 1
```